# Add some rule for XML parsing

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3

Add some rule for parsing of the XML, but it doesn't work when I try compile project. I have the next error: 
Error   2   unknown attribute reference 'closeTag' in '$closeTag.text'  D:\DevExpress\ControlEvaluation\RichEditControl\WindowsFormsRichEdit\WindowsFormsRichEdit\XMLParser.g4  40  29  WindowsFormsRichEdit
Error   1   unknown attribute reference 'openTag' in '$openTag.text'    D:\DevExpress\ControlEvaluation\RichEditControl\WindowsFormsRichEdit\WindowsFormsRichEdit\XMLParser.g4  40  8   WindowsFormsRichEdit

```
element     :   '<' openTag=Name attribute* '>' content '<' '/' closeTag=Name '>'
        |   {$openTag.text.equals($closeTag.text)}?
        |   '<' Name attribute* '/>'
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `closeTag` is defined in your first alternative, but you refer to it in the second alternative. It doesn't exist there.

Comment: will it possible add some rules, that will be check start and end tags in ANTLR?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do semantic checks in the parser. The equality of open and close tag names is a semantic enforcement. Instead parse the input without such constraints like you want to implement here and instead run a semantic phase once you got the parse tree. This will allow you also to print much better error messages (e.g. "Open and close tag must be the same", instead of "No viable alt").

For this semantic check use the generated parse tree listener (or rather your derivation of that class).